# How Can I Send 'SMS Sent Successfully' Intent to BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I edited an open source sms messaging app and I want to replace the SMS sender part. Instead of sending locally as SMS I want to change it to send/forward to my remote SMS gateway  and I want to reuse the existing sms Broadcast Receiver.  What I want to do is broadcast a successfully sent intent to BroadcastReceiver when it is successfully delivered to my remote server so that the SMSBroadcastReceiver can still do its work.

so this line should be replaced with something that send POST request to my server..

```
smsmgr.sendMultipartTextMessage(recipient, null, messages, sentIntents, null);
```

How do I fake this 'sent successfully' intent? :)

This is the method that sends SMS.

```
private void send(final String recipient, final String message) {
    Log.d(TAG, "text: " + recipient);
    int[] l = SmsMessage.calculateLength(message, false);
    Log.i(TAG, "text7: " + message.length() + ", " + l[0] + " " + l[1] + " " + l[2] + " "
            + l[3]);
    l = SmsMessage.calculateLength(message, true);
    Log.i(TAG, "text8: " + message.length() + ", " + l[0] + " " + l[1] + " " + l[2] + " "
            + l[3]);

    // save draft
    final ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(TYPE, Message.SMS_DRAFT);
    values.put(BODY, message);
    values.put(READ, 1);
    values.put(ADDRESS, recipient);
    Uri draft = null;
    // save sms to content://sms/sent
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(URI_SMS, PROJECTION_ID,
            TYPE + " = " + Message.SMS_DRAFT + " AND " + ADDRESS + " = '" + recipient
                    + "' AND " + BODY + " like '" + message.replace("'", "_") + "'", null, DATE
                    + " DESC");
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        draft = URI_SENT.buildUpon().appendPath(cursor.getString(0)).build();
        Log.d(TAG, "skip saving draft: " + draft);
    } else {
        try {
            draft = cr.insert(URI_SENT, values);
            Log.d(TAG, "draft saved: " + draft);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "unable to save draft", e);
        }
    }
    values = null;
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    cursor = null;
    SmsManager smsmgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
    final ArrayList<String> messages = smsmgr.divideMessage(message);
    final int c = messages.size();
    ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>(c);

    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "send messages to: " + recipient);

        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
            final String m = messages.get(i);
            Log.d(TAG, "devided messages: " + m);

            final Intent sent = new Intent(MESSAGE_SENT_ACTION, draft, this, SmsReceiver.class);
            sentIntents.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, sent, 0));
        }

        smsmgr.sendMultipartTextMessage(recipient, null, messages, sentIntents, null);
        Log.i(TAG, "message sent"+sentIntents);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "unexpected error", e);
        for (PendingIntent pi : sentIntents) {
            if (pi != null) {
                try {
                    pi.send();
                } catch (CanceledException e1) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "unexpected error", e1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the SMSReceiver class.

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

/**
 * Tag for logging.
 */
static final String TAG = "bcr";

/**
 * {@link Uri} to get messages from.
 */
private static final Uri URI_SMS = Uri.parse("content://sms/");

/**
 * {@link Uri} to get messages from.
 */
private static final Uri URI_MMS = Uri.parse("content://mms/");

/**
 * Intent.action for receiving SMS.
 */
private static final String ACTION_SMS_OLD = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

private static final String ACTION_SMS_NEW = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER";

/**
 * Intent.action for receiving MMS.
 */
private static final String ACTION_MMS_OLD = "android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED";

private static final String ACTION_MMS_MEW = "android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER";

/**
 * An unreadable MMS body.
 */
private static final String MMS_BODY = "<MMS>";

/**
 * Index: thread id.
 */
private static final int ID_TID = 0;

/**
 * Index: count.
 */
private static final int ID_COUNT = 1;

/**
 * Sort the newest message first.
 */
private static final String SORT = Calls.DATE + " DESC";

/**
 * Delay for spinlock, waiting for new messages.
 */
private static final long SLEEP = 500;

/**
 * Number of maximal spins.
 */
private static final int MAX_SPINS = 15;

/**
 * ID for new message notification.
 */
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID_NEW = 1;

/**
 * Last unread message's date.
 */
private static long lastUnreadDate = 0L;

/**
 * Last unread message's body.
 */
private static String lastUnreadBody = null;

/**
 * Red lights.
 */
static final int RED = 0xFFFF0000;

@Override
public final void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    handleOnReceive(this, context, intent);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
static void handleOnReceive(final BroadcastReceiver receiver, final Context context,
        final Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.d(TAG, "onReceive(context, " + action + ")");
    final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    final PowerManager.WakeLock wakelock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
    wakelock.acquire();
    Log.i(TAG, "got wakelock");
    Log.d(TAG, "got intent: " + action);
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "sleep(" + SLEEP + ")");
        Thread.sleep(SLEEP);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "interrupted in spinlock", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String t = null;
    if (SenderActivity.MESSAGE_SENT_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        handleSent(context, intent, receiver.getResultCode());
    } else {
        boolean silent = false;

        if (ACTION_SMS_OLD.equals(action) || ACTION_SMS_NEW.equals(action)) {
            Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
            assert b != null;
            Object[] messages = (Object[]) b.get("pdus");
            SmsMessage[] smsMessage = new SmsMessage[messages.length];
            int l = messages.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                smsMessage[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[i]);
            }
            t = null;
            if (l > 0) {
                // concatenate multipart SMS body
                StringBuilder sbt = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                    sbt.append(smsMessage[i].getMessageBody());
                }
                t = sbt.toString();

                // ! Check in blacklist db - filter spam
                String s = smsMessage[0].getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                // this code is used to strip a forwarding agent and display the orginated number as sender
                final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                if (prefs.getBoolean(PreferencesActivity.PREFS_FORWARD_SMS_CLEAN, false)
                        && t.contains(":")) {
                    Pattern smsPattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9a-zA-Z+]+):");
                    Matcher m = smsPattern.matcher(t);
                    if (m.find()) {
                        s = m.group(1);
                        Log.d(TAG, "found forwarding sms number: (" + s + ")");
                        // now strip the sender from the message
                        Pattern textPattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-9a-zA-Z+]+: (.*)");
                        Matcher m2 = textPattern.matcher(t);
                        if (t.contains(":") && m2.find()) {
                            t = m2.group(1);
                            Log.d(TAG, "stripped the message");
                        }
                    }
                }

                final SpamDB db = new SpamDB(context);
                db.open();
                if (db.isInDB(smsMessage[0].getOriginatingAddress())) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Message from " + s + " filtered.");
                    silent = true;
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Message from " + s + " NOT filtered.");
                }
                db.close();

                if (action.equals(ACTION_SMS_NEW)) {
                    // API19+: save message to the database
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put("address", s);
                    values.put("body", t);
                    context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),
                            values);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Insert SMS into database: " + s + ", " + t);
                }
            }
        } else if (ACTION_MMS_OLD.equals(action) || ACTION_MMS_MEW.equals(action)) {
            t = MMS_BODY;
            // TODO API19+ MMS code
        }

        if (!silent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "t: " + t);
            int count = MAX_SPINS;
            do {
                Log.d(TAG, "spin: " + count);
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "sleep(" + SLEEP + ")");
                    Thread.sleep(SLEEP);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "interrupted in spin lock", e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                --count;
            } while (
                    updateNewMessageNotification(context, t) <= 0
                            && count > 0);
            if (count == 0) { // use messages as they are available
                updateNewMessageNotification(context, null);
            }
        }
    }
    wakelock.release();
    Log.i(TAG, "wakelock released");
}


/**
 * Get unread SMS.
 *
 * @param cr   {@link ContentResolver} to query
 * @param text text of the last assumed unread message
 * @return [thread id (-1 if there are more), number of unread messages (-1 if text does not
 * match newest message)]
 */
private static int[] getUnreadSMS(final ContentResolver cr, final String text) {
    Log.d(TAG, "getUnreadSMS(cr, " + text + ")");
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(URI_SMS, Message.PROJECTION, Message.SELECTION_READ_UNREAD,
            Message.SELECTION_UNREAD, SORT);

    //Cursor cursor = cr.query(URI_SMS, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor == null || cursor.isClosed() || cursor.getCount() == 0 || !cursor
            .moveToFirst()) {
        if (text != null) { // try again!
            if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                cursor.close();
            }
            return new int[]{-1, -1};
        } else {
            if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                cursor.close();
            }
            return new int[]{0, 0};
        }
    }
    final String t = cursor.getString(Message.INDEX_BODY);
    if (text != null && (t == null || !t.startsWith(text))) {
        if (!cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return new int[]{-1, -1}; // try again!
    }
    final long d = cursor.getLong(Message.INDEX_DATE);
    if (d > lastUnreadDate) {
        lastUnreadDate = d;
        lastUnreadBody = t;
    }
    int tid = cursor.getInt(Message.INDEX_THREADID);
    while (cursor.moveToNext() && tid > -1) {
        // check if following messages are from the same thread
        if (tid != cursor.getInt(Message.INDEX_THREADID)) {
            tid = -1;
        }
    }
    final int count = cursor.getCount();
    if (!cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return new int[]{tid, count};
}

/**
 * Get unread MMS.
 *
 * @param cr   {@link ContentResolver} to query
 * @param text text of the last assumed unread message
 * @return [thread id (-1 if there are more), number of unread messages]
 */
private static int[] getUnreadMMS(final ContentResolver cr, final String text) {
    Log.d(TAG, "getUnreadMMS(cr, " + text + ")");
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(URI_MMS, Message.PROJECTION_READ, Message.SELECTION_READ_UNREAD,
            Message.SELECTION_UNREAD, null);
    if (cursor == null || cursor.isClosed() || cursor.getCount() == 0 || !cursor
            .moveToFirst()) {
        if (MMS_BODY.equals(text)) {
            if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                cursor.close();
            }
            return new int[]{-1, -1}; // try again!
        } else {
            if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                cursor.close();
            }
            return new int[]{0, 0};
        }
    }
    int tid = cursor.getInt(Message.INDEX_THREADID);
    long d = cursor.getLong(Message.INDEX_DATE);
    if (d < ConversationListActivity.MIN_DATE) {
        d *= ConversationListActivity.MILLIS;
    }
    if (d > lastUnreadDate) {
        lastUnreadDate = d;
        lastUnreadBody = null;
    }
    while (cursor.moveToNext() && tid > -1) {
        // check if following messages are from the same thread
        if (tid != cursor.getInt(Message.INDEX_THREADID)) {
            tid = -1;
        }
    }
    final int count = cursor.getCount();
    if (!cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return new int[]{tid, count};
}

/**
 * Get unread messages (MMS and SMS).
 *
 * @param cr   {@link ContentResolver} to query
 * @param text text of the last assumed unread message
 * @return [thread id (-1 if there are more), number of unread messages (-1 if text does not
 * match newest message)]
 */
private static int[] getUnread(final ContentResolver cr, final String text) {
    Log.d(TAG, "getUnread(cr, " + text + ")");
    lastUnreadBody = null;
    lastUnreadDate = 0L;
    String t = text;
    if (MMS_BODY.equals(t)) {
        t = null;
    }
    final int[] retSMS = getUnreadSMS(cr, t);
    if (retSMS[ID_COUNT] == -1) {
        // return to retry
        return new int[]{-1, -1};
    }
    final int[] retMMS = getUnreadMMS(cr, text);
    if (retMMS[ID_COUNT] == -1) {
        // return to retry
        return new int[]{-1, -1};
    }
    final int[] ret = new int[]{-1, retSMS[ID_COUNT] + retMMS[ID_COUNT]};
    if (retMMS[ID_TID] <= 0 || retSMS[ID_TID] == retMMS[ID_TID]) {
        ret[ID_TID] = retSMS[ID_TID];
    } else if (retSMS[ID_TID] <= 0) {
        ret[ID_TID] = retMMS[ID_TID];
    }
    return ret;
}

/**
 * Update new message {@link Notification}.
 *
 * @param context {@link Context}
 * @param text    text of the last assumed unread message
 * @return number of unread messages
 */
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
static int updateNewMessageNotification(final Context context, final String text) {
    Log.d(TAG, "updNewMsgNoti(" + context + "," + text + ")");
    final NotificationManager mNotificationMgr = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    final boolean enableNotifications = prefs.getBoolean(
            PreferencesActivity.PREFS_NOTIFICATION_ENABLE, true);
    final boolean privateNotification = prefs.getBoolean(
            PreferencesActivity.PREFS_NOTIFICATION_PRIVACY, false);
    final boolean showPhoto = !privateNotification
            && prefs.getBoolean(PreferencesActivity.PREFS_CONTACT_PHOTO, true);
    if (!enableNotifications) {
        mNotificationMgr.cancelAll();
        Log.d(TAG, "no notification needed!");
    }
    final int[] status = getUnread(context.getContentResolver(), text);
    final int l = status[ID_COUNT];
    final int tid = status[ID_TID];

    // FIXME l is always -1..
    Log.d(TAG, "l: " + l);
    if (l < 0) {
        return l;
    }

    if (enableNotifications && (text != null || l == 0)) {
        mNotificationMgr.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID_NEW);
    }
    Uri uri;
    PendingIntent pIntent;
    if (l == 0) {
        final Intent i = new Intent(context, ConversationListActivity.class);
        // add pending intent
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    } else {
        final NotificationCompat.Builder nb = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        boolean showNotification = true;
        Intent i;
        if (tid >= 0) {
            uri = Uri.parse(MessageListActivity.URI + tid);
            i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri, context, MessageListActivity.class);
            pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            if (enableNotifications) {
                final Conversation conv = Conversation.getConversation(context, tid, true);
                if (conv != null) {
                    String a;
                    if (privateNotification) {
                        if (l == 1) {
                            a = context.getString(R.string.new_message_);
                        } else {
                            a = context.getString(R.string.new_messages_);
                        }
                    } else {
                        a = conv.getContact().getDisplayName();
                    }
                    showNotification = true;
                    nb.setSmallIcon(PreferencesActivity.getNotificationIcon(context));
                    nb.setTicker(a);
                    nb.setWhen(lastUnreadDate);
                    if (l == 1) {
                        String body;
                        if (privateNotification) {
                            body = context.getString(R.string.new_message);
                        } else {
                            body = lastUnreadBody;
                        }
                        if (body == null) {
                            body = context.getString(R.string.mms_conversation);
                        }
                        nb.setContentTitle(a);
                        nb.setContentText(body);
                        nb.setContentIntent(pIntent);
                        // add long text
                        /*nb.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(body));

                        // add actions
                        Intent nextIntent = new Intent(
                                WebSMSBroadcastReceiver.ACTION_MARK_READ);
                        nextIntent.putExtra(WebSMSBroadcastReceiver.EXTRA_MURI, uri.toString());
                        PendingIntent nextPendingIntent = PendingIntent
                                .getBroadcast(context, 0, nextIntent,
                                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                        nb.addAction(R.drawable.ic_menu_mark,
                                context.getString(R.string.mark_read_), nextPendingIntent);
                        nb.addAction(R.drawable.ic_menu_compose,
                                context.getString(R.string.reply), pIntent);*/
                    } else {
                        nb.setContentTitle(a);
                        nb.setContentText(context.getString(R.string.new_messages, l));
                        nb.setContentIntent(pIntent);
                    }
                    if (showPhoto // just for the speeeeed
                            && Utils.isApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)) {
                        conv.getContact().update(context, false, true);
                        Drawable d = conv.getContact().getAvatar(context, null);
                        if (d instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap();
                            // 24x24 dp according to android iconography  ->
                            // http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#notification
                            int px = Math.round(TypedValue
                                    .applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 64,
                                            context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
                            nb.setLargeIcon(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, px, px, false));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            uri = Uri.parse(MessageListActivity.URI);
            i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri, context, ConversationListActivity.class);
            pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            if (enableNotifications) {
                showNotification = true;
                nb.setSmallIcon(PreferencesActivity.getNotificationIcon(context));
                nb.setTicker(context.getString(R.string.new_messages_));
                nb.setWhen(lastUnreadDate);
                nb.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.new_messages_));
                nb.setContentText(context.getString(R.string.new_messages, l));
                nb.setContentIntent(pIntent);
                nb.setNumber(l);
            }
        }
        // add pending intent
        i.setFlags(i.getFlags() | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        if (enableNotifications && showNotification) {
            int[] ledFlash = PreferencesActivity.getLEDflash(context);
            nb.setLights(PreferencesActivity.getLEDcolor(context), ledFlash[0], ledFlash[1]);
            final SharedPreferences p = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            if (text != null) {
                final boolean vibrate = p.getBoolean(PreferencesActivity.PREFS_VIBRATE, false);
                final String s = p.getString(PreferencesActivity.PREFS_SOUND, null);
                Uri sound;
                if (s == null || s.length() <= 0) {
                    sound = null;
                } else {
                    sound = Uri.parse(s);
                }
                if (vibrate) {
                    final long[] pattern = PreferencesActivity.getVibratorPattern(context);
                    if (pattern.length == 1 && pattern[0] == 0) {
                        nb.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
                    } else {
                        nb.setVibrate(pattern);
                    }
                }
                nb.setSound(sound);
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "uri: " + uri);
        mNotificationMgr.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID_NEW);
        if (enableNotifications && showNotification) {
            mNotificationMgr.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID_NEW, nb.getNotification());
        }
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "return " + l + " (2)");
    //noinspection ConstantConditions
    AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(
            new ComponentName(context, WidgetProvider.class),
            WidgetProvider.getRemoteViews(context, l, pIntent));
    return l;
}

/**
 * Update failed message notification.
 *
 * @param context {@link Context}
 * @param uri     {@link Uri} to message
 */
private static void updateFailedNotification(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
    Log.d(TAG, "updateFailedNotification: " + uri);
    final Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, Message.PROJECTION_SMS, null,
            null, null);
    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        final int id = c.getInt(Message.INDEX_ID);
        final int tid = c.getInt(Message.INDEX_THREADID);
        final String body = c.getString(Message.INDEX_BODY);
        final long date = c.getLong(Message.INDEX_DATE);

        Conversation conv = Conversation.getConversation(context, tid, true);

        final NotificationManager mNotificationMgr = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        final SharedPreferences p = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        final boolean privateNotification = p.getBoolean(
                PreferencesActivity.PREFS_NOTIFICATION_PRIVACY, false);
        Intent intent;
        if (conv == null) {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, null, context, SenderActivity.class);
        } else {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, conv.getUri(), context,
                    MessageListActivity.class);
        }
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.error_sending_failed);
        String text = null;
        final Notification n = new Notification(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning, title,
                date);

        if (privateNotification) {
            title += "!";
        } else if (conv == null) {
            title += "!";
            text = body;
        } else {
            title += ": " + conv.getContact().getDisplayName();
            text = body;
        }
        n.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, text, PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
        n.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        n.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
        n.ledARGB = RED;
        int[] ledFlash = PreferencesActivity.getLEDflash(context);
        n.ledOnMS = ledFlash[0];
        n.ledOffMS = ledFlash[1];
        final boolean vibrate = p.getBoolean(PreferencesActivity.PREFS_VIBRATE, false);
        final String s = p.getString(PreferencesActivity.PREFS_SOUND, null);
        Uri sound;
        if (s == null || s.length() <= 0) {
            sound = null;
        } else {
            sound = Uri.parse(s);
        }
        if (vibrate) {
            final long[] pattern = PreferencesActivity.getVibratorPattern(context);
            if (pattern.length == 1 && pattern[0] == 0) {
                n.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            } else {
                n.vibrate = pattern;
            }
        }
        n.sound = sound;
        mNotificationMgr.notify(id, n);
    }
    if (c != null && !c.isClosed()) {
        c.close();
    }
}

/**
 * Handle sent message.
 *
 * @param context    {@link Context}
 * @param intent     {@link Intent}
 * @param resultCode message status
 */
private static void handleSent(final Context context, final Intent intent,
        final int resultCode) {
    final Uri uri = intent.getData();
    Log.d(TAG, "sent message: " + uri + ", rc: " + resultCode);
    if (uri == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "handleSent(null)");
        return;
    }

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        final ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(1);
        cv.put(SenderActivity.TYPE, Message.SMS_OUT);
        context.getContentResolver().update(uri, cv, null, null);
    } else {
        updateFailedNotification(context, uri);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You've posted far too much code here, please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the section about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Valid Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @bluefeet sorry.. next time I'll do that and thank you for pointing this to me..

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.

My receiver for successfully sent SMS was waiting for 'MESSAGE_SENT_ACTION' intent action so I just edited few lines.

I can send the MESSAGE_SENT_ACTION intent action to my sms receiver if my sms server returns ok/200 like below.

```
final Intent sent = new Intent(MESSAGE_SENT_ACTION, draft,
                    this, SmsReceiver.class);

sendBroadcast(sent);
```

That is the only change I made and it worked given the current code I have..